# K8s: Multiple nginx-ingress-controller ingress rules in GKE

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a catch all ingress rule for a domain `*.foo.com`, and then I have one specific rule for a domain `a.foo.com`. According to the documentation, the ingress rule for `a.foo.com` must take priority over the one with a wildcard (because it's a better match than the wildcard). However, this isn't happening. How do I set priorities explicitly? What am I doing wrong?

Here's my generic ingress rule:

```
$ kubectl describe ing foo
Name:             foo
Namespace:        foo
Address:          x.x.x.x
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (x.x.x.x:8080)
TLS:
  foo.com terminates *.foo.com
Rules:
  Host             Path  Backends
  ----             ----  --------
  *.foo.com
                   /   foo:8888 (<none>)
```

Here's the domain specific rule:

```
$ kubectl describe ing foo-a
Name:             foo-a
Namespace:        foo
Address:          x.x.x.x
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (x.x.x.x:8080)
TLS:
  foo.com terminates a.foo.com
Rules:
  Host                                Path  Backends
  ----                                ----  --------
  a.foo.com
                                      /hello   foo-a:8080 (<none>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure each of your nginx-ingress controllers to have a different `ingress-class` name. Then in your ingress definition, you should specify the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "my-ingress"` to point to the ingress controller you want to use for that particular ingress.

Setup details are included in the [nginx-ingress docs].(https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. However, this will be wasting resources. My current solution to this is to use *.foo.com as the default TLS certificate, and not specify any TLS certificate name for a.foo.com.